# with XPlot/Plotly, how can I draw two graph types on each other, with F#?

Tags: f#, plotly

I would like to draw a candle chart with lines on top:

```
Chart.Candlestick candleData
```

with:

```
[aScatter; hScatter; lScatter; rvwapScatter]
|> Chart.Plot
```

as an overlay, but I can't find the right syntax to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly.NET offers several options for multiple charts, so it really just depends on what you're trying to accomplish: https://plotly.net/01_2_multiple-charts.html

Comment: this shows how to make several charts of different types in a grid. What I want is to draw a set of candle sticks and draw lines ON TOP of them

Comment: some confusion here because I'm using XPlot with Plotly, and not Plotly.NET; Combine is a function specific to Plotly.NET

Comment: I recommend using Plotly.NET. The combined chart looks to be what you're after.

Comment: Yes I just did the switch and it has all I need, besides a scaling bug :) but yes it’s much better